# sed -n function calling in same line repeatedly

Tags: sed

I'm a complete novice wrt unix and writing shell scripts, so apologies if the solution to my problem is quite banal.

Essentially though, my shell script, “run.x” is reading the same initial conditions repeatedly, when it should be reading in different ones each time. The troubled code is here, and I think the problem is with sed:

run.x:

```
./sursec.x < ./sursecout.txt
sed -n '1,2p;3q' sursecout.txt
cd ..
mv ./data ./CJ=3.029990
mkdir data
cd SurSec
```

```
./sursec.x < ./sursecout.txt
sed -n '3,4p;5q' sursecout.txt
cd ..
mv ./data ./CJ=3.030659
mkdir data
cd SurSec
```

So, the first two lines of each chunk of code above are supposed to read in two lines from the following:

sursecout.txt:

```
3.029990d0
0.81476d0
3.030659d0
0.81476d0
```

The first part of the code above should be reading in 3.029990d0, 0.81476d0, and the next part should read in 3.030659d0, 0.81476d0, respectively. These are my initial conditions, taken from sursecout.txt, and run through a separate script called sursec.x. Each of these processes then creates a folder, “CJ = …”, and stores ten output text files there. My shell script runs a total of 30 such processes. My issue is that I get 30 folders, each with the correct CJ value, but the exact same group of ten output files in each one of them. My shell script seems to repeat the same process 30 times, but store them in different folders.

Comment: It's not clear (to me) what you are trying to do. I think you run a program with an input file, and produce an output. Are you doing this once? and you want to split this output to various files? Maybe add some more details about what is this input file, what is the output (do you strore it to a file?) and what will be the result (files with 2 lines each?).

Comment: The two blocks of code above are part of a shell script called "run.x". This script tells a different script (sursec.x) to read in two values from sursecout.txt, and perform a series of integrations in FORTRAN. So, "run.x" is getting sursec.x to do this several times (30 precisely), but reading in different lines from sursecout.txt as initial conditions each time. Once the program has ran, it stores 10 output files in a specific folder, for a total of 30 folders. But instead I have 30 folders, but 300 identical files. Does that help to clarify?

Comment: I suggest you to [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/618200/edit) your question and add a minimal reproducible example with just 2 couples of output lines. What will be the content of `sursecout.txt`, what will be the output of `./sursec.x < ./sursecout.txt` and what is the result you want to have finally. Describe strictly any final files with their content, based on the input content.

Comment: I think it is much better now. You have to also update with where your fortran script saves the output files, at first place, is it hardcoded to save them at `../data` directory? It would be better to be configurable and be an argument for that script (if you control it).

Comment: Currenty the first part of your code reads all input and produce the files. Then your sed command does nothing, just prints to the output. Similarly the second part reads all input and produces the same output files etc.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, you want to read each pair of lines from your data file into `sursec.x`, and then save the resulting `data` directory with a name approximating the first value of the two lines.

```
while IFS= read -r line1 && IFS= read -r line2          # Read two lines from the datafile
do
    mkdir -p ../data                                    # Create data directory (if necessary)
    printf "%s\n%s\n" "$line1" "$line2" | ./sursec.x    # Feed the two lines to sursec
    target="CJ=${line1%d0}"                             # Prefix "CJ=" and strip trailing "d0"
    mv ../data ../"$target"                             # Rename "data" as "$target"
done < sursecout.txt
```

The reason your own code didn't work is because you don't ever modify the source data file, so the `sursec.x` program is always given the same first two lines.

I'm slightly puzzled why the `sursec.x` program should create its data files in the parent directory, but since that's what your sample code does, it's what mine assumes here too.